# How to Detect a specific sound in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am beginner in Android Programmming. Developing a **sound detection app** in Android studio. Can somebody help me to detect a specific sound ?

Comment: Well, read this! It will help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [musicg](https://github.com/loisaidasam/musicg)

**musicg** is a lightweight audio analysis library, written in `Java`, with the purpose of extracting both *high level* and *low level* audio features. This API allows developers to extract audio features and operate audio data like reading, cutting and trimming easily from an inputstream. It also provides tools for digital signal processing, renders the wavform or **spectrogram** for research and development purpose.

Add musicg library to your project and try this code :-

```
Wave w1= new Wave("first_wav"); // Base Audio file
Wave w2= new Wave("second_wav"); // Audio file to compare
// Finding Audio Fingerprint Similarity
FingerprintSimilarity fps = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(w2);
float score = fps.getScore();
float sim = fps.getSimilarity();
```

`sim` contains the *similarity* between to audio files *(value rages from 0 to 1.0)*. value greater that *`0.3`* can be considered as similar sound.musicg uses `16 bit PCM` audio files.

but getFingerprintSimilarity() accept only wave format files.

[This app](https://github.com/anoopknr/akuvo) uses musicg for sound detection.

Comment: Thanks, @anoopknr. May be I need to check the app and then clarify.

Comment: Do i have to find similarity within ".raw" file

Comment: @HerambUttarwar `.eaw` file here is a temporary file to which first the data is written and then copied to `.wav` file. So you don't need to compare the `raw` file instead compare the generated `.wav` file

Comment: Yes. I implemented the similarity module and it shows a similarity but it is not that precise. Can you describe the process in brief?

Comment: @HerambUttarwar musicg is a light weight audio similarity check tool. The noises from the outside will affect the result. I used it for detecting pre-recorded sounds. This program makes audio file to audio fingerprint and checks for maching. Similar to functioning of music app **Shazam**. For theoretical working reffer [this site](http://coding-geek.com/how-shazam-works/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference it did help but the only problem is the similarity value is deviating.

Comment: I am able to detect the sound with high amplitude but it does not detect for low amplitude. Are there any parameters that can be changed for better efficiency?